# Mount EFS in ECS and then access Python Packages from EFS

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have an usecase were I need to use multiple python packages for my ECS task. So I installed all packages in EFS storage. Te EFS includes all python packages on a mounted path (/mnt/efs/test/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages). It includes tensorflow packages as well.

While I am able to mount the EFS to ECS, and the packages are accessible, but I am facing some error while access tensorflow packages and other modules.

While ECS is trying to access the tensorflow packages it through followings, error:

```
ImportError: libtensorflow_cc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
File "/mnt/efs/test/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 63, in preload_check
File "/mnt/efs/test/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 26, in <module>
File "/mnt/efs/test/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
```

While accessing the modules I have created it through follwoing error.

```
from ..t1.test_checking import analyzer
File "/test/src/test/t1/analyzer.py", line 10, in <module>
```

The Code is copied in docker images on path '/test/'

I know the issue is related to path as the pip modules are on other path and the remaining code is on another path, how can I make changes in python code or PATH which can resolve the issue.